# Comment functionality in facebook iframe application

Tags: facebook

i have a iframe application. I want to provide comment functionality to it. How can i achieve this please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: People should be able to comment from the app to facebook

Answer (score 0):

```
<fb:comments title="My App" xid="conversation_id" width="400"></fb:comments>
```

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:comments_%28XFBML%29